# How to check update API rest

Tags: ios, web-services, api, rest

My iOS App call a API with Restful webservice API. Then I used data and saved Json data on my disk.
On next time open app, I want to check API, if having update, the app will call and be reveice data, if not update I will use data on disk.

How to check API update? Thankyou.

Comment: That very much depends on the very specific REST API you are accessing and cannot be answered in general.

Answer (score 2):

If you have influence on the API then you can make a call that returns for example a timestamp of latest update. If it is newer than the one you have on your device then download the new data. Because you probably want to avoid downloading the (same) data twice. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Yes, it is. I heard that solution is use HEAD verb instead of GET, POST. I will research it. Thankyou so much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in AppDelegate, which will be called when app come back to foreground. Call the API and check it's last modification date of you'r data.

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
}
```